# In MySQL, does the order of the columns in a WHERE clause affect query performance,why?

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-5.5

I have a query that doesn't use any indexes:

```
SELECT 32,
       guid,
       1,
       1,
       1,
       0,
       5
FROM   test
WHERE  level >= 20
       AND ( ( fun_GetIndexValue(data, 354) >> 16 ) + 
             ( fun_GetIndexValue(data, 355) >> 16 ) + 
             ( fun_GetIndexValue(data, 356) >> 16 ) + 
             ( fun_GetIndexValue(data, 357) >> 16 ) + 
             ( fun_GetIndexValue(data, 358) >> 16 ) + 
             ( fun_GetIndexValue(data, 359) >> 16 ) ) >= 1;
```

The `level` column has only about 80-90 distinct values, the table `test` has about million rows, and the `data` column is passed to the function, so I think the query can not use any indexes. But I found that if I put the `level` condition in the end, the query performs slower. Why is that?

Comment: Can you add the execution plan of both queries (level column at the start of the where clause and at the end of it), using the EXPLAIN statement (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/using-explain.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the results from the first "form" of the query are already cached ?
As lyxing said, post the execution plan. It will be interesting to see how the optimizer chooses the execution plan in both cases.

Comment: The execution plan of both queries are sameness:    id|select_type|table|type|possible_keys|key |key_len|ref |rows  |Extra
1 |SIMPLE     |test |ALL |NULL         |NULL|NULL   |NULL|221405|"Using where"

Comment: and,in my session,when i set profiling=1;then execute the statement.but when i execute "show profiles" command,no sql profile can be found.